# How can i implement this in reactjs without replace the first trigger collapse in the new one

Tags: reactjs

**I need to get the data only when the collapse is clicked or expand**

Here is the codepen on my issue - https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-hill-40gf2?file=/app.js you see how the data inside collapse is the same every time I open another collapse it will change the second collapse I click.

I'm trying to implement this in reactjs. Because right now I'm using only one state so the first data I click have data but if I click the second one the first data is gone.

How can I use or generate multiple states and use them on collapse every time I click the collapse?

Here how I filter data every single click in collapse

```
  filterIssuesByRepoId(ids){
    filterIssuesByPaginationApi(dataId, result => {
      const { data, error } = result;
      if (error) {
        // Handle error
        return;
      }

      if (data && Array.isArray(data)) {
        this.setState({
          dataId: {
            id: currentid,
            data: array
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

This is how I get the data

```
this.state.dataId.id === data.id && this.state.dataId.data && this.state.dataId.data.length > 0 ? this.state.dataId.data: noData
```

[image]

Here is my actual project. See how the first collapse data is gone I need the data still there
[image]

Comment: can you add more specific in the second photo?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-germain-rci4d?file=/app.js here the codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

[sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-sky-48x37?file=/app.js) Below code will fix your issue. just use filter to filter subData and dont update main state directory. When both toggle open then both Panel fetching data from common state so if one data changes then other data also change, hence for you it was displaying same data on opening panel.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Collapse } from "antd";

const { Panel } = Collapse;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [
        {
          id: "tests",
          data: "data"
        },
        {
          id: "ss",
          data: "dddddd"
        }
      ],
      subDatas: [
        {
          id: "tests",
          subId: "sub test",
          subData: "sssss ssss"
        },
        {
          id: "ss",
          subId: "1",
          subData: "1"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.subDatas);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.list.map((data, index) => (
          // Only do this if items have no stable IDs
          <Collapse>
            <Panel header={data.data} key={data.id}>
              {this.state.subDatas.filter(item => item.id === data.id).map((data, index) => (
                <ul>
                  <li>{data.subData}</li>
                </ul>
              ))}
            </Panel>
          </Collapse>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.3.4/antd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: here is my issue I need to call the data only when the collapse is trigger or expand

Comment: possible fix would be to change you state data structure, for example:
newSubData: {
   [id]: [data for this id]
}
this will surely help you